# Connecting to web service - The token provider cannot get tokens for target

Tags: vb.net, soap, app-config

I'm trying to connect to a SOAP web service and I get this error:

> The token provider cannot get tokens for target 'http://realurl.com/myservice.svc'

The company that made the service sent me this `app.config` sample code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <!-- Specify UserName and Password of context user -->
        <add key="UserName" value="xxxxxx" />
        <add key="Password" value="xxx" />
    </appSettings>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="ValuationServiceEndpoint" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                    openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                    bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                    messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
                    allowCookies="false" >
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                    <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
                        enabled="false" />
                    <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential" >
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName"  establishSecurityContext="false"/>
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="https://sampleurl.com/service.svc"
                binding="wsHttpBinding"  bindingConfiguration="ValuationServiceEndpoint"
                contract="Provider.ValuationService.ValuationService" name="ValuationServiceEndpoint" >
            </endpoint>
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I'm having problems with this code, though, because the endpoint address they gave me is HTTP not HTTPS. That means that the security mode `TransportWithMessageCredential` won't work here so I changed it to `Message` instead.

Here's my current code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="Username" value="myuser" />
        <add key="Password" value="mypass" />
    </appSettings>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="ValuationServiceEndpoint">
                    <security mode="Message">
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" establishSecurityContext="false" />
                    </security>
                </binding>
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://realurl.com/service.svc"
                binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ValuationServiceEndpoint"
                contract="Provider.ValuationService.ValuationService" name="ValuationServiceEndpoint" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I can't figure out why I'm getting the token error. Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sorry to answer your post 2 months later, but at least you will know why it didn't work.

Your problem was in fact simple. The security mode was mismatching between the server and your client. The server was expecting `TransportWithMessageCredential` and the client was providing `Message`.

If you only wanted to use a password security use `Message` on both side. If you wanted to use HTTPS, you need to provide `TransportWithMessageCredential` on both side.